# Is it possible to attach a security group to a load balancer ONLY IF the security group count is set to 1?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm working on a terraform module which creates a load balancer amongst other resources. I would like to attach a security group to the load balancer, but only if a a certain variable is equal to "all" OR "gw".

I currently have a count argument in place for the security group itself:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "akamai_sg" {
  count = var.domain_name_suffix == "all" || var.domain_name_suffix == "gw" ? 1 : 0
  name                   = "akamai-pl-sg"
  description            = "Manage access from Akamai to ${var.environment} alb"
  vpc_id                 = var.vpc_id
  tags                   = merge(var.common_tags, tomap({ "Name" = "akamai-pl-sg" }))
  revoke_rules_on_delete = true
}
```

This means that the security group will only be created if the domain_name_suffix is set to "all" or "gw".

I would like this same functionality  for attaching this security group to the ALB. However, I still want to create the ALB regardless of this variable, it is just the security group attachment which I want to be dependent.

Currently I have this configuration for my ALB:

```
resource "aws_lb" "internal" {
  name                       = "${var.environment}-${var.domain_name_suffix}"
  internal                   = true
  load_balancer_type         = "application"
  security_groups            = [aws_security_group.alb_sg.id, aws_security_group.akamai_sg.id]
  subnets                    = var.alb_subnets
  idle_timeout               = var.alb_idle_timeout
  tags                       = var.common_tags
  drop_invalid_header_fields = true

  dynamic "access_logs" {
    for_each = var.alb_access_logging_enabled == true ? [var.alb_access_logging_enabled] : []
    content {
      bucket  = var.alb_access_logging_bucket
      enabled = true
      prefix  = "internal"
    }
  }
}
```

However, this results in an error:
*"Error: Missing resource instance key
on .terraform/modules/comm_common/alb.tf line 5, in resource "aws_lb" "internal":
5:   security_groups            = [aws_security_group.alb_sg.id, aws_security_group.akamai_sg.id]
Because aws_security_group.alb_sg has "count" set, its attributes must be
accessed on specific instances.
For example, to correlate with indices of a referring resource, use:
aws_security_group.alb_sg[count.index]"*

When I add in this [count.index] to the ALB security group reference, I still get the same error.

Comment: What exactly is `aws_security_group.alb_sg`?

Comment: This is another security group which will need to be attached to the ALB regardless of whether domain_name_suffix is set to "gw" or "all".

Comment: The error is about that SG, as it seems it is also created with `count`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try the same condition in security_groups field as well? but the value would be a list with two items if condition is true and with one item if condition is false?

```
resource "aws_lb" "internal" {
  name                       = "${var.environment}-${var.domain_name_suffix}"
  internal                   = true
  load_balancer_type         = "application"
  security_groups            = var.domain_name_suffix == "all" || var.domain_name_suffix == "gw" ? [aws_security_group.alb_sg.id, aws_security_group.akamai_sg.id] : [aws_security_group.alb_sg.id]
  subnets                    = var.alb_subnets
  idle_timeout               = var.alb_idle_timeout
...
}
```